# How can I launch keytool.exe through a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, jdk, jre

For various reasons, I want to make a batch script that can launch `keytool.exe` from either [JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) or [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). I thought this would be rather simple, but it has proven to be rather difficult. Here are some of the methods I have used, but none of which work:

```
"keytool.exe"

cd "keytool.exe"

start "keytool.exe"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\keytool.exe"

"Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\keytool.exe"

".\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\keytool.exe"

%SYSTEMROOT%\Windows\System32\cmd.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\keytool.exe"
```

*(Note: Based on the scripts content is where I placed it, I am aware of how to properly place the script accordingly...)*

There *are* several others I used, but to avoid clutter I did not list them. I'm pretty stumped on why this isn't working, I have made *many* ***many*** batch script launchers for a wide array of programs. Is this possible? Even creating a shortcut does nothing. I assumed the shortcut wouldn't work but thought it was worth a shot anyways.

Comment: Just with above commands it will run and exit. You need to provide command line parameters for it to do anything

Comment: How so? I know that I can run it by opening `cmd` and typing `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\keytool.exe"`. Why (and how) do I use command-line parameters to run it through scripting?

Comment: what do you want to do by opening keytool?

Comment: I just want to run it so that I can make JKS, keyes, and certificates to sign APKs and JARs .

Comment: If you want to only run it but not do anything, have you tried something like `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\keytool.exe" && pause` update version as required

Comment: Write the commands which are required to do the same

Comment: Aaah, now I see what you mean by parameters, I was under the impression that I ran it, _then_ provided arguments and functions. (Obviously) I am still fairly new to `keytool`. I'll just tinker with it for now...